# How can I solve x in this shape?

Tags: geometry, angle

I've been learning angles on lines and in shapes but I've been struggling with how to go about solving this. Usually you're given more angle values or at least a side value as a starting point -  [Image of shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCyBl.png) but here it's only 90 degrees. I know the parallelogram can be split in to two triangles and that the angles opposite are equal, I also know that the angle left of the 90 is a reflex angle, I just don't know where to go from there and how to use any of that info to get to the next step. I know the answer is x= 52 but the reason wasn't given and I don't understand how they got it. Please can somebody explain it? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are any lengths or angles specified?

Comment: Only the 90 degree angle is given and they want you to find X, I had to identify a reflex and any acute angles but again, no actual extra values where given, I got it from MathsGenie site GCSE revision practice - https://www.mathsgenie.co.uk/resources/15_angles.pdf (the link is to a pdf on mathsgenie.co.uk) but they only give the answer without explaining how they got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the test paper, it asks you to *measure* it, i.e use a protractor instead of using geometry! Especially as it is only one mark they aren't after lots of work!

Comment: +1. Importantly, the list of "materials required for examination" (top of first page) includes a protractor.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked the word measure, I stupidly assumed it wasn't drawn to scale. Thank you.

Comment: And that! Thank you @Blue